# Crate DB not starting up

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, crate

I recently did an upgrade on my Ubuntu system, after which Crate DB process is unable to start with the following error, if anyone has run into anything similar please let me know how to get around this problem:

```
Jan 23 14:15:44 systemd[1]: Started CrateDB Server.
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.163920] kernel tried to execute NX-protected page - exploit attempt? (uid: 123)
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.163948] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00007f588a0fb4a0
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.163966] IP: 0x7f588a0fb4a0
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.163975] PGD 8000000260920067 
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.163976] P4D 8000000260920067 
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.163985] PUD 25e644067 
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.163994] PMD 2609bf067 
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.164582] PTE 8000000244b1b867
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.165159] 
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.166288] Oops: 0011 [#2] SMP PTI
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.166836] Modules linked in: ccm bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_match snd_soc_core snd_compress arc4 ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec intel_rapl snd_hda_core x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hwdep intel_powerclamp snd_pcm coretemp kvm_intel iwlmvm snd_seq_midi kvm snd_seq_midi_event irqbypass mac80211 snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_seq ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_seq_device iwlwifi snd_timer aesni_intel snd aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd cfg80211 input_leds intel_cstate serio_raw intel_rapl_perf soundcore hci_uart btusb serdev btrtl btqca btbcm mei_me btintel mei intel_pch_thermal shpchp bluetooth topstar_laptop sparse_keymap
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.171180]  ecdh_generic mac_hid intel_lpss_acpi intel_lpss acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio acpi_pad parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops r8169 ahci psmouse drm mii libahci video pinctrl_sunrisepoint i2c_hid pinctrl_intel hid
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.173152] CPU: 0 PID: 6247 Comm: java Tainted: G      D         4.13.0-31-generic #34~16.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.173803] Hardware name: Default string Default string/Default string, BIOS 5.12 11/25/2017
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.174446] task: ffff958d1eb00000 task.stack: ffffb60d85c1c000
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.175082] RIP: 0010:0x7f588a0fb4a0
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.175700] RSP: 0018:ffffb60d85c1ff50 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.176307] RAX: 00000000000003e7 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f5889a1c4d9
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.176908] RDX: 00007f588a0fbc50 RSI: 00007f588a0fbd30 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.177498] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000000c
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.178076] R10: 00007f588a0fb4a0 R11: ffff958d1eb00000 R12: 0000000000000000
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.178646] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.179245] FS:  00007f588a0fd700(0000) GS:ffff958d2ec00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.179817] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.180387] CR2: 00007f588a0fb4a0 CR3: 000000025e70c004 CR4: 00000000003606f0
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.180966] Call Trace:
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.181537]  ? entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x33/0xa3
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.182111] Code:  Bad RIP value.
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.182680] RIP: 0x7f588a0fb4a0 RSP: ffffb60d85c1ff50
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.183258] CR2: 00007f588a0fb4a0
Jan 23 14:15:45 kernel: [ 1421.183831] ---[ end trace 638906f36e14cf1b ]---
```

The following is my release:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The following is my dpkg output:

```
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic              4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic              4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic              4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.13.0-31-generic              4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic        4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic        4.10.0-42.46~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-26-generic        4.13.0-26.29~16.04.2                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-31-generic        4.13.0-31.34~16.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04              4.13.0.31.51                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: wow, that's strange!

Comment: hi, we've found the cause of the problem and now perform some additional tests before making a new release. the fix will be available in cratedb 2.2.x and 2.3.x

Comment: @Christian : Thanks for the update. For now I was able to start CrateDB by purging the kernel update and reverting to linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic

Comment: Yes it is indeed a regression in the kernel, where invoking a non-existent syscall leads to the kernel oops you've been observing (see bug report on launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1745123) reverting the kernel is the way to go. however, we removed the unnecessary syscall from our codebase, too.